# What kinds of inconsistencies would one get if one starts with Lorentz noninvariant Lagrangian of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

What kinds of inconsistencies would one get if one starts with Lorentz noninvariant Lagrangian of QFT? The question is motivated by [this preprint arXiv:1203.0609](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0609) by Murayama and Watanabe.

Also, what is the basic difference between

- a theory that is non-relativistic approximation to relativistic theory, and
- a fundamentally Lorentz non-invariant theory?

Comment: arXiv:1203.0609 is also discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87792/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 1):

Lorentz invariant theories are desirable because their behaviour does not depend on a specific frame of reference.

A theory non-relativistic approximation to a relativistic theory can usually be acquired by expanding physical quantities which are part of a relativistic around low velocities or momenta. 
A fundamentally Lorentz non-invariant theory is just some theory which does not possess the property of Lorentz-invariance.